# SimpleUrlHandlerMapping do not work

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to create simple urlMapping, but it doesn't work. It goes into constructor, but don't go into preHandle() or postHandle(). Here is xml part:

```
 <bean id="handlerMapping"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                 <prop key="/*">loginFilterSpring</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="loginFilterSpring" class="com.spacebattle.filters.LoginFilterSpring"/>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

**UPD:** 
I created controller, but its method handleRequestInternal() never been called. Any ideas?

```
<bean id="handlerMapping"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="loginFilterSpring"/>
            </list>
        </property> 
        <property name="mappings">

            <value>
                /*=loginFilterController
            </value> 
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="loginFilterSpring" class="com.spacebattle.filters.LoginFilterSpring"/>

    <bean id="loginFilterController" class="com.spacebattle.filters.LoginFilterController"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mappings` property of `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` is for your controllers. You seem to be supplying it with a `HandlerInterceptor`, which it will just ignore.

You should specify interceptors in the `interceptors` property, not the `mappings` property. You then need to put a proper controller into the `mappings` property.

Comment: Yes, you is right. But then, how should I map my interceptors, not controllers?

Comment: @Mikhail: If you need different interceptors for different paths, then you need to use multiple `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`s. The interceptors supplied to a given `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` apply to all of the controllers in that `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`.

Comment: Thank you, now I understands how this works. However, my controller throws an exception: javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler [com.spacebattle.filters.LoginFilterController@5ad52411]: Does your handler implement a supported interface like Controller?<br/> The @Controller annotation doesn't help.